# How to check if my other apps are installed on iOS 10?

Tags: ios

Until iOS 9, we were able to use `canOpenURL` method to check if there are apps who can handle specific URL schemes, thus it was widely used to check if a specific app was installed by user.
Now, since iOS 9, we have to declare upfront the URL Schemes that can be checked by the app. This is cool in general, but it means that for every release of a new app, we would have to update previous apps to be able to check if the new one is installed or not.

Is there any sane way to do it now?
I guess most of the ads and cross promotion services out there relies on this and had to adapt somehow, anyone knows how?

Thanks
Krystian

Comment: One of the way is that use the website URL to open that App for example http://map.apple.com will open Apple Maps. This creates a dependency on the other app developers.

Comment: @New16 but it's my own check. I need to know if my other apps are installed or not and I would like to control this without republishing my app. I download a list of apps from server and check which ones are installed. Now that won't be possible.

Comment: I don't think so there is any other way. The next would be to use MDM concepts, which is not a feasible solution at all.

Comment: How would you imagine a MDM would work in regards of ios privacy policies? There's no way to match a single user/device only by starting an app.

Comment: @Krystian, you say _"I download a list of apps from server and check which ones are installed. Now that won't be possible."_, but you don't see the same case from a most important perspective: the __end-user's privacy__. Apple explicitly tries to prevent developers to violate the end-user's privacy uncontrollably so if the developers intend to collect marketing information about the device, Apple wants to keep that under control as much as possible; that is what you are facing to here.

Comment: @holex nope.. I think your and Apple's views are very limited. End user's privacy is not violated in any way in my case. The whole thing is intended to improve their experience with the apps. Apple does not want to keep that under control, they have disabled the ability and that's it. There's no control here. They are only forcing me to update apps I would not need to update. The only reason of the update is to add a single entry to the Info.plist file. Where's privacy control here?

Comment: @Krystian, c'mon. Q: why would an app like to check the other installed app dynamically on certain devices in background? A: _marketing purpose_ and who knows what else you would collect in your app about the end-user and building a huge database using or selling to third parties. the control is if your app suspiciously monitors that in that background, and that is clearly not related to your app's original purpose (e.g. harmless dating-app where users share more private information about themselft via), Apple will be able to disable your app remotely immedetaly undoubtably. you are funny. :)

Comment: @holex no you are funny. There's nothing blocking me from doing that, I just have to update the app to include more and more schemes. Just because dynamite can be used to make harm, it's not the only way it can be used. Seriously, open your eyes.

Comment: @Krystian, you can update your app as many times you'd like to, extending the `info.plist` file and going through the review procedure each occasion; nobody prevents you to do so, but the developers (especially app-developer companies) won't be able to embed such hidden features into their client's applications anymore to take advantages of someone else's applications for their own benefits. that is very simple to understand, you don't need to victimise yourself, you may not do any harm and you also have a legal way to work around this issue – under a strict control by Apple.

Comment: @holex i understand that. I fail to understand though, about what developer control are you talking about? Preventing other devs from taking advantage of one's app. What's that suppose to mean? Is there a list one can sign up to,which says 'don't use my scheme'?

Comment: @Krystian, let's go back in time: at first e.g. the UDID was available for anyone to indetifiy the user (=device), but app devs started using it for tracking the device only and purchasing-selling behaviours of people; then Apple stopped granting access to UDID. another example the `SKProduct` could have been generated programmatically by devs and they tricked the end-user by showing a lower _tier_ for the purchase than the actual payment was; Apple started giving access `SKProduct` only via StoreKit; and the list goes on, but it may show the violations in past and how Apple corrected it.

Comment: @Krystian, and the current situation is pretty much the same category; even if _you_ are using it responsibly, it does not mean everyone does, and Apple just changes the rules to protect their consumers' privacy. you (or I) may have different views about _privacy_ than Apple does but they don't care about devs at all, everything which they do or will do is for their consumers' best interests only. it can be a long conversation, but I don't want to _off_ this thread, I only hope I could show the point and the basic pricipal behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so to recap.

Currently, the only way to handle my scenario, is to assign a specific scheme per app in an orderly fashion, for example:

```
my.domain.app01
my.domain.app02
...
```

If you have apps already released, just update them to add a new, additional scheme.

Now in Info.plist file, you will have to add all of your existing and future schemes to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` list in Info.plist.
The idea is: even though you have 10 apps released, you add entries for let's say 40. This way, you will not have to update your app to add schemes for future apps, they will already be there and you will be able to detect them.

This of course covers my scenario, where I want to be able to detect my own apps and make use of them.

Remember, that your app can handle more than one scheme, so you can assign the internal scheme + use something better named to allow external access to your app.